# Heroku open is not working when working with node / express app

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I am getting an error when trying to run "heroku open". It is saying that it tries to run the application with npm start but then  "Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch" happens. I am using macOS with npm jazz.

Here is a pic of my logs.
[image]

At first i thought it was because i was not adding "start" in my package.json but that didnt seem to work either.

Comment: can you show your server code ? specifically the part where you are assigning port to the server ?

Comment: Sorry here is link on twitter im not aloud to post pictures yet https://twitter.com/andrewdevlopmen/status/996501724675411968

Comment: not this one. The code part. where you are creating your server

Comment: my index.js https://twitter.com/andrewdevlopmen/status/996522005582237698